# VSFTPD Virtual Hosts

Tags: ftp, virtual-host, vsftpd

as far as i know, FTP supports HOST header for some time. So what i want to do is, run vsftp (can run multiple instances if need be) with different hostnames which point to different folders. One folder will be used for anon logins the other will be used for local logins.

Is it possible to do this?

Summary

ftp://test.test.com --> /home/test/ (anon login)

ftp://test1.test.com --> /var/ftp/  (local login)

Comment: Only _some_ FTP servers support the `HOST` command.  And it looks like `vsftpd` does not (as of the most recent version at this time, 3.0.3).  Thus I suspect you would need multiple `vsftpd` instances, and different IP addresses for your different DNS names, to make the above work.

Comment: Yeah i guess proFTPd supports it but i couldn't get it to work.